# Maven multi-threaded build: force the packaging module to run last

Tags: java, multithreading, maven

I have a multi-level maven project with the following structure:

```
+ project
    + subproject1
        + 1_module1
        + 1_module2
        + 1_module3
        + 1_module3
    + subproject2
        + 2_module1
        + 2_module2
        + 2_module3
        + ...
    + subproject3
        + 3_module1
        + 3_module2
        + 3_module3
        + ...
    + packaging-project
```

The `packaging-project` packages the build artifacts of the subprojects, and declares `pom` type dependencies on `subproject1`, `subproject2`, and `subproject3`. This (correctly) puts it last in the reactor build order, and therefore this works perfectly fine with a single-threaded build.

However, with a multi-threaded build (e.g. `mvn -T4`) the `packaging-project` build is executed by maven **before** all of the subproject modules are built.

One solution I've found is to explicitly list every module of every subproject as a dependency in `packaging-project`. However, this is annoying and brittle -- every time a new module is created, it has to be listed explicitly in `packaging-project` or risk breaking the build.

Another solution is to run `packaging-project` via a profile, and then execute it explicitly in a separate `mvn` call subsequent to the primary build. This is a good solution but requires an extra step at build time.

Is there another way to declare a build-order dependency between `packaging-project` and every module of the listed subprojects, without explicitly declaring each submodule of each subproject as a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware the only way to make one module build being dependent on others is to make them a dependency of that build, which as you state means having a manually maintained list. Your description should give you the clue: that module is *dependent* on another.

Comment: Well sure, but making a module *dependent* on another shouldn't mean it has to be *explicit*. I specifically asked for a solution that expressed the dependency relationship without having to explicitly configure it for each and every module.